# Docker compose up not showing console output for link

Tags: logging, docker, docker-compose, stdout

`docker-compose up` isn't showing the log output (stdout) for all my services.

I get output when I run the container manually:

```
$ docker run -it simple/cra-products /usr/local/bin/cra-products
[Info#INIT] cra-products
[Info#CONFIG] loadConfig
...
```

But when I run it with docker-compose, the output stops at attaching.

```
$ docker-compose up cra-products
underwriting_cra-products_1 is up-to-date
Attaching to underwriting_cra-products_1
```

I've verified that it is on, and working (my other service can connect to it). I just can't see the log output.

The log output DOES work for the other container.

```
$ docker-compose up underwriting
underwriting_cra-products_1 is up-to-date
Starting underwriting_underwriting_1
Attaching to underwriting_underwriting_1
underwriting_1  | HELLO
...
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to see the logs for all the containers.

Calling `docker-compose stop` and `docker-compose rm` and starting over doesn't fix it. Neither does using `docker-compose up -d` with `docker-compose logs`. Still no output for cra-products.

Here's the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:

  underwriting:

    image: simple/underwriting

    command: /usr/local/bin/underwriting

    links:
    - cra-products

    ports:
    - "8011:8011"

    environment:
      - UNDERWRITING_PORT=8081
      - CRA_PRODUCTS_ENDPOINT=http://cra-products:8081

  cra-products:
    image: simple/cra-products:latest
    command: /usr/local/bin/cra-products
    ports:
    - "8081:8081"

    environment:
      - CRA_PRODUCTS_PORT=8081
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Setting the service to buffer stdout by line fixed the problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you set "the service to buffer stdout by line"?

Answer (score -2):

Connecting services via links are now deprecated, as can be seen here in Docker's documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/link-env-deprecated/

As mentioned by the docs:

> Instead, you should use the link name (by default, the name of the linked service) as the hostname to connect to.

To quickly illustrate this I put together a simple example with `jadametz/dpat` (which just returns the host name) and `nginx:stable-alpine`.

```
version: '3'
services:
  dpat:
    image: jadametz/dpat
    ports:
      - 8081:80

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - 8082:80
```

Now, from within the nginx container (and after installing curl), you can see that by just references the other service, we're able to get a response.

```
[04:24 PM]~/projects ➭ docker exec -it desktop_nginx_1 ash
/ # curl http://dpat
{
  "node": "809250c001c8"
}
```

So for your `docker-compose.yml` file you can likely simply down to the following:

```
version: "3"
services:
  underwriting:
    image: simple/underwriting
    command: /usr/local/bin/underwriting
    ports:
      - "8011:8011"

  cra-products:
    image: simple/cra-products:latest
    command: /usr/local/bin/cra-products
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OPs question